# why does this console.logconsole.log(data.lyrics) gives me undefined in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Would you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetchData = (url) => {

    const [data,setData]=useState( [] );   

        useEffect(()=>{
            fetch(url,{
                crossDomain:true, 
                headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
            })
            .then(res =>{
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(dataa =>{
                /* setData(dataa.message.body.track_list.map(trc =>{
                    return [[trc.track.track_name],[trc.track.artist_name],[trc.track.album_name]];
                }));*/
                setData(dataa.message.body);
                
                /* data.message.body.track_list.trac.track.map((trac)=>{
                })
                console.log(data);
                console.log(dataa.message.body);*/
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            console.log(data.lyrics);
        },[])
    return data;
}
 
export default useFetchData;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling `data` from inside the `useEffect` hook, you're only getting the value of `data` at the point where the hook was executed. `setData` doesn't update the `data` variable immediately, but updates the state and triggers a rerender of the component.

If you move the `console.log(data.lyrics);` out of the hook, you'll see that once the component is rerendered its value should be correct.

Comment: it worked but it gives me undefined at first and then it gives me the data,how can i solve this cuz i want to use the returned data in another component

Comment: Because you're loading data from another source, there's always going to be a moment where there's no data yet, so it's up to you how to deal with that.

Typically you would have the component that uses this hook render an "empty" or "loading" state if `data` is undefined.

Comment: would you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-liskov-5im6p?file=/src/App.js:843-1066